# JPA Criteria API - where condition with field on subclass

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have entity called `Issue` and entity called `UserIssue`. `UserIssue` extends `Issue`.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity(name = "ISSUE")
public class Issue extends VersionedSequenceIdEntity {
... all fields
}

@Entity(name = "USER_ISSUE")
public class UserIssue extends Issue {

    ...

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY", nullable = false)
    private IssueCategory category;

    ...
}
```

I need to do e.g. something like this:

```
Predicate predicate= root.get("category").in(IssueCategory.CATEGORY_1, IssueCategory.CATEGORY_2);
```

The problem is that root is instance of `Root<Issue>` but "category" field is defined on subclass `UserIssue` so the line of code obviously does not work.

Is there a way how to build a predicate that creates where condition for subclass field? I have only instance of `Root<Issue>, CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder`.

Thank you,
Lukas

Comment: Add your entities in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Issue> issueQuery = cb.createQuery(Issue.class);
    Root<Issue> issueRoot = issueQuery.from(Issue.class);

    Subquery<UserIssue> subQuery = issueQuery.subquery(UserIssue.class);
    Root<UserIssue> userIssueRoot = subQuery.from(UserIssue.class);

    Predicate predicate= userIssueRoot.get("category")
          .in(IssueCategory.CATEGORY_1, IssueCategory.CATEGORY_2);
    subQuery.select(userIssueRoot).where(predicate);

    issueQuery.select(issueRoot).where(issueRoot.get("id").in(subQuery));
    em.createQuery(issueQuery).getResultList();
```